# disabling auto-increment in datanucleus?

Tags: mysql, jdo, datanucleus

I have 2 my-sql databases (live-db, test-db). I need to transfer some tables from live-db to test-db in datanucleus jdo implementation.

The problem is, if primary-key is an auto-increment then it does not transfer same value, but it generates new value.

Is there any method disable the auto-increment in datanucleus as programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

spent 5 min and cannot find the answer, so i think easiest way is to do the following:
1) add new INT column without AUTO_INCREMENT
2) copy column value
3) drop AUTO_INCREMENT column

Comment: thanks for reply, I can solve as manually, but I have to solve as programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

So you could use one set of metadata for one datastore (with autoincrement) and one set for the other (without). JDO persistence is simply following your instructions in auto-increment